# Execute sequence of various operations from the beginning while condition is true

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I need to find the best solution (mostly in complexity/speed, not about readability or RAM allocation) to execute a custom sequence of different operations (eg. function calls) as long as a condition is true. If it gets false, we must stop the sequence. Here is a solution as example :

```
/*This function starts when "condition = true", and
must stop running when "condition = false"*/

public void sequence(){
    //Every function has a duration lower than a milisecond
    function_a();

    if( condition = false ) return;

    function_b();

    /*--------------------------------
    same pattern * 20 (approximation)
    ---------------------------------*/

    if( condition = false ) return;

    function_z();

    //END of the sequence
}
```

Another example more readable than the previous one :

```
public void sequence_switch(){

    int currentStep = 0;

    do{
        switch(currentStep){
            case 0:
                function_a();
                break;

            case 1:
                function_b();
                break;

            /*--------------------------------
            same pattern * 20 (approximation)
            ---------------------------------*/

            case 2:
                function_z();
                break;
        }

        currentStep ++;
    }while( condition = true );
}
```

I have been thinking about exceptions, but in some cases they make the program slower, maybe it isn't the case here?

More informations : this sequence will most of time (95%) either have to stop while the first 5 operations are executed, or reach its end. (imagine a mechanical arm that has to move an object at different points, if it didn't grab the object correctly it will quickly fall, so all the following operations shouldn't be executed)

It is CRUCIAL to stop the sequence as soon as the condition is false.

EDIT : other solutions are welcome, but the real answer would be a comparison in terms of efficiency. 
The perfect situation for this loop would be something like a macro in a game : the condition could be "holding a key", and if you are not using this complex macro at the right time, you want to cancel it (you don't want the program to continue this sequence, you want to recover full control of your mouse/keyboard). But if it started well, you will just hold until the end except in some rare cases.

Comment: If you use java8, you can add the functions to a list, and call them using a loop.

Comment: You wrote "....have to stop while the first 5 operations are executed", are we talking about multi-threading here?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson We can talk about multi-threading, as the "condition" needed to continue the sequence will not change in this "sequence()" function. Its update will actually come from another thread/process.

Comment: Did you consider instead of setting a variable in this "other thread" you can send message to your first thread (the one we are talking about here).  Then an Interrupt exception can happen and you would just need to catch this on the outside.

Comment: @LucA What does each function return? If multi threading isn't involved, you could just do `return function_a() && function_b() && function_c()....` and make every function return a boolean value of `true` or `false`.

Comment: @vivek_23 None of the functions must return something, the main point is being able to start this sequence and stop it.

Comment: @Alfe I considered exceptions, i wrote it in my question. I would like to have some comparisons in terms of speed, as exceptions may be very slow (around 5ms). But you are right, using an exception is another solution to stop the sequence. The question is, what would be the more efficient?

Comment: @LucA You said `It is CRUCIAL to stop the sequence as soon as the condition is false.` so how would you know when to stop? I saw you did a `if( condition = false )` in your first attempt.

Comment: @vivek_23 the "checks" in the sequence are located after some very fast operations : "Every function has a duration lower than a milisecond". Even on a game, this shouldn't be a problem. But i see where you are going, an exception would detect the condition at anytime. The problem is there : in what conditions the if list (exemple 1) will stop the sequence faster than an exception? But how much slower can these if be if we don't have to stop the sequence? The main point of my question is finding a balance between these ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first solution have perfect performance, it is impossible to do better.

Comment: Maybe uncomplete, but efficient answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you are willing to sacrifice readability, there's always room to improve performance.  In this case you could inline the code of the functions instead of calling them.  (Which shows the dubiety of the whole question, btw.)